# project with my son

Tags: hardware

I am doing a pi project with my son.  For the first part of the project he built a meccanno car and now we are going to power it.

My setup is illustrated here: https://prnt.sc/nb8oph

As you can see my setup consists of 4 components:
1. H-Bridge (https://www.ebay.com/itm/2X-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Stepper-Motor-Driver-Controller-Board-Arduino/382579265852?hash=item591380513c:g:oFoAAOSwszVbs4sl&frcectupt=true)

2. Power Supply (https://www.ebay.com/itm/4-5V-Power-Supply-3-x-AAA-Battery-Holder-Enclosed-Case-Box-Switch-Wire-Lead-2pcs/322095307119?hash=item4afe60596f:g:9DwAAOSwjARcZO7w&frcectupt=true)
3. 4.5v meccano motor (unable to find a link)
4. Raspberry Pi 3

I have a two questions based on my diagram:
1. Are my parts and "plugging ins" correct if I want to control the motor with a pi?
2. Where does GPIO2 from the pi plug into the bridge? GPIO->IN1?

Please help my son, he really likes this stuff and I want this to work for him.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you please specify what kind of motor you're using? I'm assuming it's a DC motor, but just to be sure.

Comment: why is it important that this is for your son? The answer will not be a function of whom the project is for!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you wire what you showed us up and it did not work? What is the behavior?

Comment: @David thanks, and here is a link to the car: http://www.meccano.com/product/p21333/meccano---off-road-racer-25-in-1-motorized-building-set I THINK it is a DC motor so let's assume first that it is
@.JayEye I know it does not matter that the project is for my son, I just thought people may have wanted to know who they were helping.  Anyway no I have not tried this because the power supply is late in the mail.  Even if I had it I would not try it without asking in case I burn something out in the trial.  I am trying to do ask this and get it solved before the piece comes to minimize wait time.

Comment: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy/2

Comment: @CoderMike wow thanks, that guide is perfect and exactly what we need!